# SQL Server GROUP BY clause returning many results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am having an issue when joining three tables and using GROUP BY in SQL Server.
The query below returns MANY results for each Material # which is the main item I care about grouping by.

When I run this query I get multiple results for each value, sometimes with identical column values and sometimes very different.
Our dates only use the calendar date not a time stamp so maybe many records in one day on various tables are returning many values?
I am a bit lost on this.

The query is built from an Access query which returns a couple hundred results while this returns 4k plus due to each value being repeated many times.
There should only be one result for each article # and size, but I am seeing sizes repeated many times.

I gues that this has something to do with the joins, because removing them and their related select items, it returns normal.

```
SELECT          P.PLANT_CODE,
            P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
            P.MATERIAL,
            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
            P.PERIOD_CODE,
            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
            P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
            P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
            P.SIZE_LITERAL,
            P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
            P.PLANNED_QTY + P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY',
            (T.DELIVERY_QUANTITY - T.RECEIVED_QUANTITY) AS 'PO_UNDELIVERED_QTY',
            I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
            I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY - P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'ARTICLE_BALANCE'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
                VW_INTRANSIT_ITEM T
 ON             P.MATERIAL = T.MATERIAL
                VW_INVENTORY I
 ON             P.MATERIAL = I.MATERIAL
 WHERE          I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY - P.PLANNED_QTY <> 0
 GROUP BY                       P.PLANT_CODE,
                    P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                        P.MATERIAL,
                        P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                        P.PERIOD_CODE,
                    P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                    P.PLANNED_QTY,
                        P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                        P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                    P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                    P.PLANNED_QTY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                (T.DELIVERY_QUANTITY - T.RECEIVED_QUANTITY),
                I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY - P.PLANNED_QTY
       HAVING               P.PLANT_CODE IN (6040,6041)
       AND                  P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
       AND                  P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN (00,01,'ZU','Z2')
       AND                  P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - 60
       AND                  P.PLANNED_QTY > 0 
       ORDER BY             P.PLANT_CODE,
                        P.MATERIAL,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX;
```

Comment: If you want one row per article # and size, then GROUP BY only the article # and size!  Your entire HAVING clause belongs in your WHERE clause - use the HAVING for filtering based on aggregates.  If your joins are giving you more rows than you want, then you need to look at the data - if you want 1:1 joins, then make sure you join to a UNIQUE index/constraint on the target table.

Comment: Your GROUP BY clause is much more inclusive than your question text says you want (i.e.: far too many colums). If Access is "doing it right" then try using SQL Profiler to capture the actual SQL being submitted from Access to see where its GROUP BY clause is different, because it sure won't be what you've posted here.

Comment: Thank you for the answers - still a bit of a newbie on this. I thought  the same thing about the GROUP BY clause - limiting it to the material # but when I do it returns error that the values in SELECT list must be in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.